# Linq - One to many relationship, order by rules

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables:

```
TranslationCode:
  Id  Name
  1   'User'
  2   'Role'

Language:
  Id
   1
   2
Translation:
 TranslationCodeId  LanguageId  StoreId (Allow Null) Value
   1                   2           null               'User'
   1                   2           1                  'Person'
   2                   1           null               'Роль'
```

I need select all translations with TranslationCodeId and Value depends on LanguageId and OrganizationId. 
For example:

```
LanguageId = 2 StoreId = null
TranslationCodeId  Value
 1                 'User'
 2                 'Роль'

LanguageId = 2 StoreId = 1
TranslationCodeId  Value
 1                 'Person'
 2                 'Роль'
```

I implemented it by this way

```
var languageId = 2;
IEnumerable<object> result = _unitOfWork.DbContext.Set<TranslationCode>().Select(t => new {
    t.Id,
    v = (
         t.Translations.Any(l => l.StoreId == storeId && l.LanguageId == languageId) ? t.Translations.First(l => l.StoreId == storeId && l.LanguageId == languageId).Value :
         t.Translations.Any(l => l.LanguageId == languageId) ? t.Translations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LanguageId == languageId).Value :
         t.Translations.FirstOrDefault().Value
     )
});
```

Does someone have more elegant idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does someone have more elegant idea?

Well, the answer is in the question title - *order by rules*, i.e. order the sequence by the priority of the elements you want and than take the first, for instance:

```
v = t.Translations
    .OrderBy(l => l.LanguageId == languageId ? (l.StoreId == storeId ? 0 : 1) : 2)
    .Select(l => l.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```